# Why the brower's address doesn't change when rails redirect_to successfully invoke the new url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4. and I've tried

`redirect_to queue_url` or `redirect_to '\queue'`.

both successfully send a GET request to the correct url, handled by the correct action, and the web page has been refreshed with the correct content.
However, the brower's url still remains unchanged.
But I'm expecting the url to be changed to `\queue`.
This is annoying because if the user then refresh the page, the page is refreshed to the original url.

Is anything wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this is a known limitation of redirect in Rails, see [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/37) and [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/22).